# Using Render Section script on MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I create two Render Section on `_Layout.cshtml` bellow:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
@RenderSection("scriptpartial", required: false)
```

Page Index.cshtml using reference from `_Layout.cshtml`, on page `Index.cshtml` I use define code:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("This is code 1");
        });
    </script>
}
```

Page `Index.cshtml` contain one partial `_Other.cshtml`, in file `_Other.cshtml` I define code:

```
@section scriptpartial {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("This is code 2");
        });
    </script>
}
```

When I running application, only "This is code 1" executed, I do not know error this

Comment: @sections are ignored in partial views. You have to render it from _Layoout or index.

Answer (score 1):

You have to place your scriptpartial section on the Index.cshtml page, because unfortunately @sections are not possible in partial views.